# Elements overflows the flex from top of container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
/* Side Bar */

#sidebar {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: blueviolet;
    height: 92%;
    width: 17%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.side, .subs {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#things, #others, #subscriptions {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#things div, #others div, #subscriptions div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}

#things div i, #others div i, #subscriptions div i {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<!-- sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="things">
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-house side"></i><p>Home</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-regular fa-compass side"></i><p>Explore</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-s side"></i><p>Shorts</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-photo-film side"></i><p>Subscriptions</p></div>
        </div>

        <div id="others">
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-file-video side"></i><p>Library</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-clock-rotate-left side"></i><p>History</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-play side"></i><p>Your Videos</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-regular fa-clock side"></i><p>Watch later</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-up side"></i><p>Liked Videos</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down side"></i><p>Show more</p></div>
        
        
        </div>

        <div id="subscriptions">
            <h4 class="subs">SUBSCRIPTIONS</h4>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-circle side"></i><p>TKA Team</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-circle side"></i><p>Freecodecamp</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-circle side"></i><p>Crypto Gurus</p></div>
        
        
        </div>

    </div>
```

How can I prevent the elements from overflowing the container from the top even when the browser is resized?

[Image of the overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvmRg.png)

PS: I want to leave the items centered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reset `padding`, `margin`, and `box-sizing` at the top of the scope -

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


#sidebar {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: blueviolet;
    height: 92%;
    width: 17%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.side, .subs {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#things, #others, #subscriptions {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#things div, #others div, #subscriptions div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}

#things div i, #others div i, #subscriptions div i {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="things">
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-house side"></i><p>Home</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-regular fa-compass side"></i><p>Explore</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-s side"></i><p>Shorts</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-photo-film side"></i><p>Subscriptions</p></div>
        </div>

        <div id="others">
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-file-video side"></i><p>Library</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-clock-rotate-left side"></i><p>History</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-play side"></i><p>Your Videos</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-regular fa-clock side"></i><p>Watch later</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-up side"></i><p>Liked Videos</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down side"></i><p>Show more</p></div>
        
        
        </div>

        <div id="subscriptions">
            <h4 class="subs">SUBSCRIPTIONS</h4>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-circle side"></i><p>TKA Team</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-circle side"></i><p>Freecodecamp</p></div>
            <div><i class="fa-solid fa-circle side"></i><p>Crypto Gurus</p></div>
        
        
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Always rest default browser padding, margin & box sizing behaviour